# "Thanks for having me"

Tags: meaning, phrases, politeness

Recently, I finished my phone job interview with the phrase "Thanks for having me". It was a reply to the other person's "Thank you for your time". So, does "thanks for having me" sound alright in this context?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No. "Having me" implies "having me over", usually in the sense of for a visit or stay, so wouldn't be right in a professional context even if face to face.

I would suggest a response of simply "thank you" to "thanks for your time" as an appropriate professional alternative that will also work on the phone.

Comment: Ok, thank you. The reason I used that phrase is that I'd heard it many times on the radio (American NPR station), where people who talked with the program host over the phone (reporters or those being interviewed) would say it quite often.

Comment: Interesting.  I suppose it could be seen in that context as "thanks for having me on your show" - a response to a host.

Answer (score 2):

Not really; I'd use this as a polite farewell phrase on leaving a dinner party or having visited friends for the weekend; see [here](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/Thank+you+for+having+me). I wouldn't think it quite in order for a business arrangement; perhaps a simple *no trouble, thank you* would be better.